# How do I query to fetch number of Posts made by a User using mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregate, mern

So I'm trying to fetch the total number of posts done by a specific user.

**Models**

**Post.ts (In post model I have user ref)**

```
user: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
      required: [true, "Please provide user ID."],
    },
```

I tried

```
const posts = await Post.find({ user: req.user._id});
const postCount = posts.length;
```

But I want to aggregate the User so I can ***get the user data along with the post counts***.
what I tried is below but I'm getting 0 number of posts.

```
const user = await User.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "post",
          let: { userId: "$_id" },
          pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$userId", "$userId"] } } }],
          as: "posts_count",
        },
      },
      { $addFields: { posts_count: { $size: "$posts_count" } } },
    ]);
```

I searched but couldn't find any related answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slightly alter the query as follows. From the `post` model, I see that the field referenced for user collection is `user`. In the aggregate, you have used `$userId`.

```
const user = await User.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "post",
          let: { userId: "$_id" },
          pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$userId", "$user"] } } }],
          as: "posts_count",
        },
      },
      { $addFields: { posts_count: { $size: "$posts_count" } } },
    ]);
```

Let me know if this helps. Thanks

Comment: It's getting all users and also doesn't return the counts as well.

Comment: Ok its works I changes from : "post" to from: "posts" it successfully returned the post counts but returning all users.

Comment: Ok. So you want to return only the specific user? In that case we can use a $match condition before the $lookup.

Comment: That's good to know. Happy coding!